# What is the minimum length of Payment ID?

Tags: payment-id

On the [official web site](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/moneropedia/paymentid) it says that Payment ID

> consists of 32 bytes (64 hexadecimal characters) or 8 bytes (in the case of integrated addresses).

Can it be less? If no, why?

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure the payment id can be shorter, and it is simply padded if it's too short. That said it shouldn't matter too much as it is encrypted so only the sender and receiver knows the contents.

Comment: monero-wallet-cli (and MyMonero) will currently reject hex strings of "invalid" length, rather than padding them. One could pad your preferred ID with zeros and use that, however.

Comment: Note that you have to use an integrated address to use encrypted payment IDs. By default they are in plain text, you can search and see them on any block explorer for instance.

Comment: I tried Poloniex and a shorter PID (less then 64) was not accepted - so same result as Luigi said. I'm not sure if we can say that it can be shorter without padding. Is it possible on network/protocol level and right now it's just disallowed in software (wallet)?

Comment: "payment ID" and "short payment ID" have specific definitions in the code and need to be the appropriate length. However, you can make up other fields in the extra field of whatever length if you so desire.

Comment: @ferretinjapan can you edit your answer according to comments so I can accept it? Mainly first sentence seems to be not accurate.